# Unity3D: how to add models dynamically at runtime in unity web output?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am new to unity 3D
I want to create a building, then the user can add new features at runtime.

What I need is a GUI with the available items from a folder. Then when pressing an item in the GUI, you can create an instance of the item.

Hovering over the building, the item may be placed in specific locations. for instance, user may not place a door on the roof. Once user hovering over an appropriate location, he is  allowed to release and place the texture or furniture.

How can I achieve that?
Please Help. Thanks Advance

Answer (score 2):

Create a BuildingBluprint or BuildingLayout  class which contains list of all items that the building can contain and the possible positions and rotations which they are allowed to have,

Then make a building Instance which contains information about the contained items and there position, allow the user to instantiate new items and every time the user moves the item check the Building Blueprint class for the closest position which the item is allowed to have. then snap to that position

You can also assign catagory to items, like FLOOR_ITEMS,DOORS, WALL_DECORATION
so that you dont always have to store all possible positions as it is not always possible to define definate positions for all items,these assigned catagorys can tell possible positions or can instead be assigned conditions to check if possition is valid,

eg-
If I am having a flower pot I will assign it a FLOOR_ITEMS catagory as it has to be placed on the ground. To check if the placement by the user is valid I can compare it with floor heights of all my floors in the building and the floor area bounds,
also I can use the same code for checking for all floor items,,

Similarly I can write code for WALL_ITEMS,

For itmes which can only be placed in certain fixed positions I can directly specify the list of possible positions